# Extraindo duas informações via Selenium e colando em apenas uma célula no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando extrair algumas informações web Via selenium, o ponto que estou travando é o seguinte: Consigo direcionar a informação do selenium buscada na internet e salvá-la dentro de uma célula específica, porém o que preciso seria, que em uma consulta dois campos fossem buscados e a informação fosse jogada para apenas uma célula, separando-as por espaço. Alguma sugestão?

Segue um exemplo:

```
'Logradouro

  Sheets("CONSULTA").Cells(Lin, 6) = selenium.findElementByXPath("//tr[7]/td").Text
```

tentei da seguinte forma:

```
'Logradouro

  Sheets("CONSULTA").Cells(Lin, 6) = selenium.findElementByXPath("//tr[7]/td", "//tr[8]/td").Text
```

Porém sem sucesso, a informação desta forma aparece em branco.

Comment: É muito feio fazer assim?

`string.Format("{0} {1}", selenium.findElementByXPath("//tr[7]/td").Text,
selenium.findElementByXPath("//tr[8]/td").Text); `

Comment: Experimente (//tr)[7]/td

Comment: Muito Obrigado, deu certo (Y)